# Uploads with white space in file name is causing errors on my server

Tags: regex, node.js, file-upload, formidable

I have a server that is used to allow people to upload files.  Unfortunately my script allows people to upload files with blank spaces in the file name.  When links to these files are generated (also by my script) the file name is output with these empty spaces.  These files can then not be downloaded by my Python script (which is also attached).  My question is obviously how best to fix this problem.  I am not sure if it is to:

A: Use some sort of regular expression to change the file name upon uploading, or

B: if there is a way I can reference the actual file name on my server (which I do not even know because when I ssh in it looks like the correct file path does actually have spaces in it).

I am very interested in what the best solution to this problem is.  Thanks.

Here is my server code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    util = require('util'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    qs = require('querystring');

var formidable = require('formidable'),
    mime = require('mime');


function dirTree(filename) {
    var stats = fs.lstatSync(filename),
        info = {
            name: path.basename(filename),
            path: ip + ':' + port + '/uploads/finished/' + path.basename(filename),
            type: mime.lookup(filename).substring(0, 5)
        };
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        info.type = "folder";
        info.children = fs.readdirSync(filename).map(function (child) {
            return dirTree(filename + '/' + child);
        });
    }
    return info;
}


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    if (request.method.toLowerCase() == 'get') {
        var filePath = './content' + request.url;
        if (filePath == './content/') {
            filePath = './content/home.html';
        }
        if (filePath == './content/feed') {
            var a = dirTree('./content/uploads/finished');
            response.end(JSON.stringify(a));
        }
        var extname = path.extname(filePath);
        var contentType = mime.lookup(extname);
        fs.exists(filePath, function (exists) {
            if (exists) {
                fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, content) {
                    if (error) {
                        response.writeHead(500);
                        response.end();
                    }
                    else {
                        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': contentType});
                        response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                    }
                })
            } else {
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm;
    if (request.url == '/upload') {
        var oldPath,
            newPath,
            fileName;
        form.uploadDir = './content/uploads/temp/';
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
            type = files['upload']['type'];
            fileName = files['upload']['name'];
            oldPath = files['upload']['path'];
            newPath = './content/uploads/finished/' + fileName;
        });

        form.on('end', function () {
            fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    response.end('There was an error with your request');
                    console.log('error')
                } else {
                    response.end('<h1>Thanks for uploading ' + fileName + '<h1>');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}).listen(port);
```

Here is the Python download script that is having the issues.

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = '192.241.228.76:9090'
def test():
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.241.228.76:9090/feed')
        readd = response.read()
        data = json.loads(readd.decode(response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')))
        if "children" in data:
            for i in range(len(data['children'])):
                kind = data['children'][i]['type']
                url = 'http://' + data['children'][i]['path']
                name = 'media/' + data['children'][i]['name']
                if kind in ('video', 'image'):
                    try:
                        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, name)
                    except:
                        try:
                            print('Spaces in ' + url)
                        except:
                            print('weird in file name')
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Applications shall be able to handle whitespaces.

In a browser, you change whitespace into `%20`, example:

```
http://foo.bar/my%20cat.jpg
```

Though the my%20cat might not look pretty, in that case you can replace whitespace with underscore (`_`) using:

```
filename.replace(new RegExp(find, ' '), '_');
```

For the python script, replace the `urllib.request.urlretrive....` with:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(urllib.quote(url + '\' + name))
```

Don't forget to add `import urllib.quote`

Comment: Thank you.  It is not just a browser.  I am using python to download files, and it returns an `Error invalid ""` error, I guess because it can't handle downloading file names with the spaces? (Which would make sense to me).

Comment: python is a programming language, not a download tool, be more specific. Show us how do you try to download, with code if possible.

Comment: Thank you. That script is also now in the question.

Comment: If my python suggestion does not work, can you print the output of url + name and try it yourself in a browser, to see if the path is actually correct.